# Can't DROP TABLE because unknown table (ERROR 1051)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to drop a table from a schema I inherited. When I `SHOW TABLES` I get

```
+----------------------------+
| Tables_in_schema_a         |
+----------------------------+
| table_1                    |
| table_2                    |
| table_3                    |
| table_4                    |
| table_5                    |
| table_6                    |
+----------------------------+
```

But when I execute `DROP TABLE table_1` I get

> ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'table_1'

I'm using the correct schema. What's going on?

P.S. This is MySQL server is 5.1.73.

Comment: Do you have the correct database selected when running your DROP statement?

Comment: @SteveMoore I'm sure that I do. I can `DESC table_1` and run `SELECT * FROM table_1`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out `SHOW TABLES` is actually a bit of a misnomer. That table, `table_1`, was unknown because it's actually a view. I ran `SELECT table_name, table_type FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='schema_a'` showed that it's a view. `DROP VIEW table_1` deleted it.

Answer (score 10):

Check whether the table is a `VIEW`, if so use the command

```
drop view table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following command:

`DROP TABLE database_name.table_name;` or
 `` DROP TABLE `table_name`; ``

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).